# How to give a rigorous proof of a fact about convex polygon?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, convex-analysis

I claim that there exist universal constants $0<\delta_1(m), \delta_2(m)<1$ such that for any convex polygon $P$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $m$ faces,
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathcal{H}^{n-1}\bigl(\bigl\{x \in \partial ^*P \, : \, \frac{x}{|x|} \cdot \nu_P(x)<\delta_1(m)\bigr\}\bigr)}{\mathcal{H}^{n-1}(\partial P)}\ge \delta_2(m), \quad \quad (*)
\end{equation}
where $\mathcal{H}^{n-1}$ is the $n$-dimensional surface measure and $\partial ^*P$ denotes the set of points on $\partial P$ where the unit outer normal vector $\nu_p$ exists.

---

The claim above should be very elementary and makes a lot of sense geometrically except for the bad notation, but I have trouble giving a rigorous proof.

My attempt:

If $n=2$, and if the origin $O$ is contained in $P$, then suppose $AB$ is the largest edge of the polygon $P$, then $OA+OB \le \mbox{the sum of the other edges} \le (m-1)AB$, hence $\angle AOB \ge \arcsin{\frac{1}{m-1}}$, where the first inequality is because $\Delta AOB$ is convex. Therefore, there is a good portion of $AB$ on which the inner product of the normal vector and polar vector is bounded away from $1$, by a positive constant depending on $m$.

My question:

If the origin $O$ is not contained in $P$, then I have trouble in showing $(*)$. I know it is definitely correct, but I just don't know how to use mathematical rigor to prove it.

For $n \ge 3$, I'm not sure whether it is the same argument as for $n=2$ to prove $(*)$ for the case $O \in P$, and I've totally no idea about proving $(*)$ for the case $O \notin P$.

Can anyone give me a rigorous proof? Thank you in advance!